# Permalinks not working on new site

Tags: permalinks

I'm setting up a new site on 3.4.1 and the Permalinks will not work.

I have deactivated all plugins and switched to TwentyEleven and they still fail.

I can see through outputting $wp_rewrite that the rules are being flushed when I chnage the structure, and .htaccess is being updated, but no matter what I do, I just get a 404 error.

I also notice that it doesn't matter what structure I use (excluding default), all links are in the format of the /%postname%/ structure.

Any suggestions of what else I can try? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a valid `.htaccess` file in your site root?

Comment: Yes, the `.thaccess` file is available and being updated when I change the Permalink structure. Have deleted and ensured that a new one can be created also, and that worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was always getting a server generated error, a friend of mine pointed out that this meant the `.htaccess` file was not even being read.

He advised checking the `.conf` file for the site, and sure enough, there was a typo in the `<Directory /var/www/...>` entry, meaning that the directory was not being read correctly when a user visited the site.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any custom post types? Is there any chance that a page or post is using the same slug as a custom post type?

Also, does your home page work or is it a 404 for all pages?

Comment: Thank you King Li, but this is sorted now.

Comment: Ok that's good to hear anyway!